# How do I connect to postgres docker image from my ruby docker application?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have two separate project. First one is my main application which is written in ruby. And the second one is my postgresql database project. I want to keep database separate from my main application.

Below is my docker-compose.yml of my main application:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Below is my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: forbinary_cms_development
  username: postgres
  password: password
  host: localhost
```

Below is my docker-compose.yml for my postgres project:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:10.10
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
volumes: 
     postgres-data:
```

Now my question is that how do I connect my main application docker image with this postgres docker image? I want to keep both - main application and database in seperate docker image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

1. My preferred way and I think this is recommended way - to put both services in one docker compose file https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links
2. You can expose DB port and access it from web server using host IP
3. You can configure in both docker-compose files to use same network and configure IPs for each service.